# How I can add my datagridview in an existing excel file using c#

Tags: c#, excel

Hello well I have this problem,The code only it can create a new excle file but I want to export my datagrid in a existing excel file.
Any help is appreciated.

```
     try
        {
            if (DataGridView1.DataSource != null)
            {
                SaveFileDialog fichero = new SaveFileDialog();
                fichero.Filter = "Excel (*.xls)|*.xls";
                if (fichero.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application aplicacion;
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook libros_trabajo;
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet hoja_trabajo;
                    aplicacion = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                    libros_trabajo = aplicacion.Workbooks.Add();
                    hoja_trabajo = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)libros_trabajo.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

                    //exportar cabeceras DataGridView1
                    for (int i = 1; i <= this.DataGridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
                    {
                        hoja_trabajo.Cells[1, i] = this.DataGridView1.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;
                    }

                    //Recorremos el DataGridView rellenando la hoja de trabajo con los datos
                    for (int i = 0; i < this.DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < this.DataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
                        {
                            hoja_trabajo.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = this.DataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
                        }
                    }

                    libros_trabajo.SaveAs(fichero.FileName, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal);
                    libros_trabajo.Close(true);
                    aplicacion.Quit();
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pertinent to your task, use the underlying `DataTable`

```
DataTable dt = DataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable;
```

and export data from that DataTable `dt` to Excel using the following procedure, which utilizes `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` object library:

```
/// <summary>
/// export DataTable to Excel (C#)
/// </summary>
internal static void Export2Excel(DataTable dataTable)
{
    object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application _appExcel = null;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook _excelWorkbook = null;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet _excelWorksheet = null;
    try
    {
        // excel app object
        _appExcel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

        // excel workbook object added to app
        _excelWorkbook = _appExcel.Workbooks.Add(misValue);

        _excelWorksheet = _appExcel.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet;

        // column names row (range obj)
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range _columnsNameRange;
        _columnsNameRange = _excelWorksheet.get_Range("A1", misValue).get_Resize(1, dataTable.Columns.Count);

        // column names array to be assigned to _columnNameRange
        string[] _arrColumnNames = new string[dataTable.Columns.Count];

        for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            // array of column names
            _arrColumnNames[i] = dataTable.Columns[i].ColumnName;
        }

        // assign array to column headers range, make 'em bold
        _columnsNameRange.set_Value(misValue, _arrColumnNames);
        _columnsNameRange.Font.Bold = true;

        // populate data content row by row
        for (int Idx = 0; Idx < dataTable.Rows.Count; Idx++)
        {
            _excelWorksheet.Range["A2"].Offset[Idx].Resize[1, dataTable.Columns.Count].Value =
            dataTable.Rows[Idx].ItemArray;
        }

        // Autofit all Columns in the range
        _columnsNameRange.Columns.EntireColumn.AutoFit();
    }
    catch { throw; }
}
```

just pass `dt` as an argument. Optionally, upon data export completion you can save the `Workbook` and `Quit` Excel app. Furthermore, as mentioned in the comments thread, you can open the existing Excel file (e.g. "MyExcelFile") and export data to that file, or just re-write the existing file by saving the newly created `Workbook` (i.e. `_excelWorkbook`) under the old file name.

The core idea of proposed solution is to run data export procedure on the underlying `DataTable` rather than `DataGridView` and export entire data `Row` at once (instead of cell-by-cell) for better performance.

Hope this may help.

Comment: This is helpful, but you OP wants to export to an existing worksheet, so what he really wants instead of `_excelWorkbook = _appExcel.Workbooks.Add(misValue);` in your code is `_excelWorkbook = _appExcel.Workbooks.Open("FileName");` You might want to add the filename as a parameter to the function you posted.

Comment: @user1274820: That's right, the main data export procedure can be further customized pertinent to particular task. The core concept/functionality is to perform data export on underlying DataTable, as shown in the solution above. Best regards,

Comment: I deleted my answer, but if you look at his code, you can see that he already has the data export down - he is just trying to figure out how to export to an existing workbook.

Comment: @user1274820: I understand that. The User can either re-write the existing file by saving the new one with the old file name, or open and save the existing file. The data export procedure would be more efficient if performed on the underlying DataTable rather than DataGridView. Best regards,

Comment: I am very confused, I have near to 656 complete rows and I want to extra information or extra rows in my excel file

Comment: Sorry, I did not quite understand your additional question/problem. Would you please post it separately to avoid the overly-long comments thread? Thanks and regards,